# Accessing properties of a tag within a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an **a** tag as follows:

```
<a href="data1.html" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"> 
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>Root Folder
</a>
```

I have a function that gets called when you click on **a** tag. It is as follows -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").hover(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.href);
   });
});
```

I can access the properties of **a** tag. Example: If i want to access the href of the **a** onclick, I can get it by event.target.href.

I want to access the properties of the **i** tag that is inside the **a** tag (for instance, class of **i** tag is "**glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close**"). 
How do I achieve that?

Also, what changes do I have to make to the function, such that it is called only if **a** tags of class = "**list-group-item**" are clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const iTag = event.target.children[0];`
`console.log(iTag.className);`

Comment: Try `$(this).find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-folder-close')` to find an element with a given class ... or maybe `$(this).find('i').attr('class')` to get the `i` tag's class

Comment: And to limit to anchors with a given class `$("a.list-group-item").hover(function() {...}`

Comment: Simply taking the time to [Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com) would answer this and other basic/rudimentary questions you have about jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to access the properties of the `i` tag that is inside the `a` tag

Inside any jQuery event handler, `this` refers to the element on which the event was triggered: therefore you can use any selector relative to that element. `$(this).children('i')` for example will find the contained `i` given your HTML; if the element might be nested more deeply you'd want `.find()` instead of `.children()`.

> what changes do I have to make to the function, such that it is called only if a tags of class = "list-group-item"

Change the selector you're using to attach the handler - `$("a.list-group-item")` instead of `$("a")` to limit it to items having that class.

Note also that if you want this to work on click as you describe, rather than on hover as in your sample code, you'll need to return false from the event handler (so that the regular link navigation doesn't occur).

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("a.list-group-item").click(function() {
    var myChild = $(this).children('i')
    
    console.log(myChild.attr("class")); // for example
    return false; // prevent regular navigation from occurring on click
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com" class="list-group-item">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i> Will fire handler on click
</a>
<br>
<a href="https://example.com">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i> Will navigate normally
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Only use list-group-item
   $("a.list-group-item").hover(function(event) {
     var $attrNode = $(this).find("i");
     //Now that you have the list group item it is easy to get the attribute
     var attributeValue = $attrNode.attr("your-attribute");

     //You can also set the attribute
     $attrNode.attr("your-attribute", "attribute value");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, this will be very easy!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.list-group-item").click(function(event) {
        $(this).find('i').attr('class');
    });
});
```

To get only certain anchor tags you can use a selector, read more about them [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Then you can use the this object to find children. Use the `find` method in jQuery. Finally use the `attr` to retrieve the class.